# How do I capture syslog data sent to a specific port

Tags: linux, parsing, syslog

I have a firewall that sends the data to our remote Linux server on the specific port. I would like to capture that data and parse it to store in DB.

So far I have tried tcpdump, nc and few others without much success. Any help is appreciated.

`tcpdump -ni device port 1234 -s0 -w capture.pcap`

> ÿÿEH¶@0c:EJ"@Ï¹ r¢"ó<30>device="SFW" date=2018-06-15 time=04:10:49
>   timezone="EDT" device_name="XG210" device_id=C2205ACMBG9B65A
>   log_id=010101600001 log_type="Firewall" log_component="Firewall Rule"
>   log_subtype="Allowed" status="Allow" priority=Information duration=0
>   fw_rule_id=2 policy_type=1 user_name="" user_gp="" iap=4
>   ips_policy_id=0 appfilter_policy_id=0 application=""
>   application_risk=0 application_technology="" application_category=""
>   in_interface="Port1" out_interface="" src_mac=00: 0:00: 0:00: 0
>   src_ip=111.11.1.111 src_country_code=R1 dst_ip=111.111.11.11
>   dst_country_code=USA protocol="TCP" src_port=61257 dst_port=80
>   sent_pkts=0  recv_pkts=0 sent_bytes=0 recv_bytes=0 tran_src_ip=
>   tran_src_port=0 tran_dst_ip=111.16.1.1 tran_dst_port=3128
>   srczonetype="LAN" srczone="LAN" dstzonetype="WAN" dstzone="WAN"
>   dir_disp="" connevent="Start" connid="2721376288" vconnid=""
>   hb_health="No Heartbeat" message="" appresolvedby="Signature"

Comment: What went wrong when you used tcpdump?  How about just saving the text file produced by syslog on the target machine?

Comment: tcpdump -ni device port 1234 -s0 -w capture.pcap did create file, however, there are special characters in the file. Due to this, I am not able to parse the same.

Comment: Please show your code and state the error or problem. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: I have added tcpdump output and information to the question.

Comment: These are not syslog lines, as to [RFC5424](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424). What is the formating of these data? What sends these data? syslog-ng? journal? syslogd? rsyslog? What it's configuratinon? Should we beleave that [firewal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) sends this data? What's the firewall then? iptables? nftables? How does it send data to tcp? And can't you just remove `sed 's/.*device=/device=/'` the special characters from the stream?

Comment: I see.  This is not a programming question, and is a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/38626/how-can-i-read-pcap-files-in-a-friendly-format  You'll find a solution there.

Comment: @KamilCuk It is messed up syslog data, it has most of the values that needs to be part of syslog.

Comment: You have  Sophos XG?

Comment: Yes, I am forward Sophos XG logs to a remote Linux server and I want to capture it so that it can be parsed easily and stored in DB.

Answer (score 1):

We have started using https://www.graylog.org. It was easy to configure on DigitalOcean hosting.

**Steps:**

1. Configure your firewall etc to send the data to your graylog on certain port
2. Configure graylog to listen to that particular port
3. Then you will see the data in graylog

Hope this helps.